# eclipse for php: why syntax coloring go crazy?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

see screen capture:
[alt text http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/5397/capture1q.png](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/5397/capture1q.png)

OS: win.
Eclipse and PDT: latest stable.
Rebooting no take effect.

Comment: Is that the entire source code? Is there anything above it? Try putting that snippet in its own file to ensure that's actually where the problematic syntax is

Comment: Use a better IDE, Eclipse was horrible when I used it last. Took an hour to load, much better off with something like Notepad++

Comment: Matt, yes, this is entire source and it works fine

Comment: Jason Lewis, I migrated to Eclipse from Notepad++ for more complex development.

Comment: @Jason Lewis: Notepad++ is not really an IDE, just a fancy text editor.

Comment: Really? Notepad++ offers more then enough features for me (tabbing and code highlighting). Heaps of people want to use IDEs that display errors and what not. Meh, I just run my code to see if there are errors. I found large IDEs like Eclipse, PHP Developer and Dreamweaver hog too much resources for me.

I'd rate PHP Developer over Eclipse though, so perhaps give that a try.

Comment: @Jon Cram: True, and it's still better then most IDEs.

Comment: @Jason Lewis: True, modern IDEs can be resource hogs and a serious developer needs a hefy machine. Still, if you can get the machine to power an IDE you'll find the productivity benefits are huge. Code completion and on-the-fly syntax checking speed up development immensely.

Comment: +1 Jon Cram, especially when you use a php framework.

Comment: @Jon Cram: Each to their own I suppose. I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to things like IDEs, as I've tried a few before and they failed to impress me. At the moment, since I'm really only coding for myself, and occasionally the odd job, I don't see the need for an IDE. Perhaps one day. But I do agree, IDEs are useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try [netbeans](http://netbeans.org) for php. You must be love it. I used to use eclipse but now I'm using netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You can report a bug [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT). I'd suggest trying it in Eclipse 3.6 and PDT 2.2 first.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that it is the entire source.  Maybe you need this at the top:

```
<?php
```

?